How to get singlespacing to only change matrix environments?
This is similar to both this and this post, but I feel like it's different enough to be it's own question.
I need to cancel the \doublespacing command, but only for matrix environments (\begin{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix in particular).
I am aware that
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1}}
will cancel double space for all of math mode, is there a way to target the matrix environment specifically?
Minimal working example which demonstrates both what I want and the issue:
\usepackage{amsmath} %Needed for matrices
\usepackage{setspace} %Needed for \doublespace

\begin{document}
%The matrix style I want
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
\doublespacing
%The matrix style I'm getting given the way I'm formatting my text,
%which I unfortunately cannot change.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
\end{document}



It may be possible to use TABstacks instead of bmatrix, depending on the extent of your application, but without a representative minimum working example, it is hard to tell.

Compile
\documentclass{article}% or any other
\usepackage{amsmath} %Needed for matrices
\usepackage{setspace} %Needed for \doublespace

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\textbf{baselinestretch is \baselinestretch}

\bigskip

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}

and you'll see, besides the unsightly matrix,

baselinestretch is 1.667

Now you know the factor to apply in order to fix the stretching, namely the inverse, which is 0.6.
Caveat. The test of \baselinestretch shown at the beginning may give different figures if you use 11pt or 12pt as document class option, so ensure to do it with your settings.
Now try
\documentclass{article}% or any other
\usepackage{amsmath} %Needed for matrices
\usepackage{setspace} %Needed for \doublespace
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\doublespacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{0.72}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\lvert x\rvert=\begin{cases}
x & x>0 \\
0 & x=0 \\
-x & x<0
\end{cases}
\]
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}

You also need to patch cases (if you employ it), or it would be unsightly as well.

Comparison
Changing neither \arraystretch nor cases

Changing only \arraystretch

Comments
By default, cases changes \arraystretch to 1.2, which adds to the horror, as you see. So we multiply the factor by 0.6 and get 0.72.
You see that you need both changes.
Avoid using $$ in LaTeX document.
Use a similar procedure if you switch to \onehalfspacing.
